# In wso2 stream processor how to change the query dynamically

Tags: wso2, siddhi, wso2-streaming-integrator

wso2 stream processor i am using as a complex event processing engine. So, I want to integrate this with front-end application so that dynamic querying can be made. I want only query and retention period(if exists) to be change dynamically using front-end application. How can we achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Stream Processor [app management REST API](https://docs.wso2.com/display/SP430/Siddhi+Application+Management+APIs) to deploy/undeploy apps. You FE application can make REST calls hand handle dynamic deployment.